# JSON get array key from data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to get the array key from a parseJSON function. I can get the error message just fine - struggling to find a way to get the array key.

code is:

```
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

console.log(result['error']);
console.log(result);
```

I am only sending one key through and the output looks like this:

```
Object {error: "Please enter a name"}
```

Comment: Please show us what does the response JSON look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you need to get the json `key` name in a variable

try this:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value){ console.log(key, value); })
```

where `result` is a json structure i.e.

```
result = { 'Name':'anything'};
```